# Searching for the top 5 largest numbers in an array

Tags: python

Coding a dice game.
I have a csv file. (score.csv)

I have put this file into an array.

```py
import csv

with open('score.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    data = list(csv.reader(csvfile))
print(data)
```

I would like to know how I can read the top 5 largest numbers from this and print them in order.

Comment: Sort it, slice it, loop and print

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sort it, select the top five and print them in order

```
data.sort(reverse = True)
top = data[:5]
for score in top:
   print(score)
```

Comment: `list.sort` is an in-place operation. _sorted_ will be assigned _None_, not to mention shadowing built-in function `sorted`

Comment: Thanks, you just let me pass my GCSE. #ez

Answer (score 0):

Taking an example:

```
data = [1241,19246,273,1204,12948,652,385,21984]
```

To get the top 5, in order, we simply do this:

```
print(sorted(data)[-5:])
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to use the `heapq` package.

As far as I know it generally has a better performance than `sorted`.

```py
from heapq import nlargest

data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
print(nlargest(5, data))
```

The output is:

```
[10, 9, 8, 7, 6]
```

It all comes down to what you want to do with the data but I find this method a bit cleaner than using `sorted`.